# How to fix permission denied for .git/ directory when performing git push?

Tags: linux, git, file-permissions, chmod, chown

I have set up a git repository on my server. Created a new user 'git'. My repos are located in `/srv/git/example.git`. I was able to `git remote add origin git@domain/srv/git/example.git` then I added and committed my changes.

However when I tried `git push origin master` it failed on:

> fatal: unable to create temporary file: permission denied' and 'fatal: sha1 file  write error: invalid argument'

On the server I ran:

```
sudo chown -R git:git /srv/git/`
```

This fixed my problem but I am wondering if this was the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> On the server I ran sudo chown -R git:git /srv/git/ - this fixed my problem but I am wondering if this was the correct thing to do?

Absolutely. The problem previously was that the git user, who you're logging in as via SSH, could not write to the repository.

Depending on your needs, you may consider different combinations of users and SSH keys, or one of the many additional programs (gitolite etc) that can be used to more finely control access.

Answer (score 12):

First, fix file permissions in your remote `.git` dir e.g.

```
sudo chmod -R ug+w /var/www/.git
sudo chown -R git:git /var/www/.git
```

or `root:root` if you want to assign members of `root` group for push access.

Then git repository on the destination host needs to be set as shared, so the following command on remote needs to be run:

```
git config core.sharedRepository group
```