# Git checkout permission denied

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I restart the VS code and switch from one branch to another branch its showing as .env permission denied. I switched to new branch but can't able to unstage, and commit this branch bez of permission denied.

```
    e5608MINGW32 /c/workspace/myworkspace/angular/project (sprint15/feature/IS-894-locally-installed-application-issue)
    $ git checkout sprint/IS-1767-in-tune-API-UI
    error: unable to create file .env: Permission denied
    Checking out files: 100% (98/98), done.
    Switched to branch 'sprint/IS-1767-in-tune-API-UI'
    D       .env
    Your branch is up to date with 'origin/sprint/FIS-1767-in-tune-API-UI'.
    e5608MINGW32 /c/workspace/myworkspace/angular/project (sprint/IS-1767-in-tune-API-UI)
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like an issue with git.  What operating system are you on?

Comment: .env fle modifed, i hope so

Comment: Close all the open files, whatever is running, vs code. Then try again. Basically RESTART.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43900127/6309), this is usually seen when another Windows process is keeping an handle on the resource (here `.env`) to modify.

Another would be when two processed are running with different account.

- one with [WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)
- one with the regular Windows account

In all cases, as commented, closing/restarting should help.

Comment: Thanks once system restart its working fine.  Now I can able to checkout the branch